# Who am I ? Born high only to fall low

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am born high only to fall low, attention !
>
> Leopard and I share a similare taste for fashion.
>
> I may be browsing for Charles's hypothesis on my evolution.
>
> My toes are even and It is as if I look upon them from heaven.
>
> In this category, no one is larger then me.
>
> If I keep fighting. Mine will become bald, no more hairy.
>
> Me and my genus fight neck and neck for hierarchy.

This is my first one, I hope it's not to easy and you have fun.
I will accept awnser with all lines explanations.

Comment: Actually, you can comment on your own questions and any answers to it

Comment: Actually, you can comment on an answer to your question.

Comment: Do you *really* mean "Mine's", or is that a grocer's apostrophe? (Just asking, because it makes a difference in how I interpret the line)

Comment: @LindaJeanne Mmmh, you are right. I wanted pluraI 'mine', I think I can edit to "Mine" and it will still work. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it:

> Giraffe

I am born high only to fall low, attention !

> Giraffe babies fall out of their standing mothers.

Leopard and I share a similare taste for fashion.

> Giraffes share a similar colouring to leopards.

I may be browsing for Charles's hypothesis on my evolution.

> It's debatable but there is a theory that Giraffes evolved long necks to browse/eat high leaves.. Marius' answer mentions that neck-fighting was a factor.

My toes are even and It is as if I look upon them from heaven.

> Giraffes have two toes on each foot, and look down on them from their heads high up on their long necks.

In this category, no one is larger then me.

> Giraffes are the tallest land animal (largest is probably not quite right.. elephants are bigger). Largest even-toed ungulate? (hippo is probably larger) Largest Giraffidae? From OP: Largest ruminant.

If I keep fighting. Mine's will become bald, no more hairy.

> From [Wild Life Ranch Texas](http://www.wildliferanchtexas.com/giraffe/): "Giraffes’ horns, or ossicones, are cylinder-shaped, short, thick, and covered with hair. The male giraffe’s ossicones are generally larger than the female giraffe’s ossicones and are bald on top due to fighting with other males."

Me and my genus fight neck and neck for hierarchy.

> Giraffes fight by slapping necks

Comment: Great, but (4) and (5) are incomplet

Comment: Like you mentionned tallest in (5), it should be referred in (4).
Hint for (5) : Elephant might (is) not be in this category ;) Girafe **is larger**

Comment: @Walker I feel like that covers it! 4 does mention the height now.

Comment: no "l" in my name. I think (5) is still not there. I don't know if your statement is true though. Because even-toed ungulate containt hippopotamus, wich I would consider _larger_ then giraffe

Comment: @Waker Apologies for the typo... Hmm, good point about the hippos, but honestly do you really expect me to hunt down the exact category that the giraffe is the largest of? Maybe 'Giraffidae' but there are only two living species in that Family.

Comment: Alright, I will give it to you, it was the larger ruminant

Comment: Google may be your friend here ;) it is in the first line of [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe)

Comment: Thanks @Jordy. I'd like to point out 'In this category' would suggest that the category is actually alluded to in the last line, but I see nothing that would clarify 'this category' to ruminant.

Comment: @Arth Noted, it was my first time, some grammar and words may not have been thought thoroughly enough. My english is also a WIP.

Comment: @Waker the word 'incomplete' is incomplete. ;)

Answer (score 5):

My shot:

> Giraffe

I am born high only to fall low, attention !

> Giraffes give birth standing up so the baby giraffe comes into this world with "a boom"

Leopard and I share a similare taste for fashion.

> Similar coloring

I may be browsing for Charles's hypothesis on my evolution.

> There are a couple of theories about why giraffes have such long necks. Some scientists believe it's simply a matter of natural selection. Giraffes fight by beating each other with their heads and necks. This is called “necking." Source: http://wonderopolis.org/wonder/why-do-giraffes-have-long-necks/ So this is a reference to Darwin's theory of evolution

My toes are even and It is as if I look upon them from heaven.

> Giraffes have 2 toes of the same length on each foot and it looks down on other creatures from a big height.

In this category, no one is larger then me.

> "The giraffe is the tallest mammal in the world, with even new-born babies being taller than most humans." Source http://www.onekind.org/education/animals_a_z/giraffe/

If I keep fighting. Mine's will become bald, no more hairy.

> Because the way the giraffes fight by slamming their necks parts of they necks become bald after a too many fights.

Me and my genus fight neck and neck for hierarchy.

> Giraffes fight using their necks.

Comment: (4), (5), (6) need a little more work, you might get the accepted awsner if you find it first.

Comment: @Waker. That's the best I can do. If this is not enough, I quit :)

Comment: Quite good but like I mentionned to Arth, heigth is used for (4), (5) talk about something else.
I see how confusing it can be now, I used toes and _them_ in the same sentence, _them_ should refere to others creatures not to toes